# Only the last line of a multiline file / string is printed

Tags: python, python-2.x, line-endings

I searched a bit on Stack Overflow and stumbled on different answers but nothing fitted for my situation...

I got a map.txt file like this:

```
+----------------------+                          
|                      |                          
|                      |                          
|                      |                          
|        test          |                          
|                      |                          
|                      |                          
|                      |                          
+------------------------------------------------+
|                      |                         |
|                      |                         |
|                      |                         |
|       Science        |       Bibliothek        |
|                      |                         |
|                      |                         |
|                      |                         |
+----------------------+-------------------------+
```

when I want to print it using this:

```
def display_map():
    s = open("map.txt").read()
    return s


print display_map()
```

it just prints me:

```
 +----------------------+-------------------------+
```

When I try the same method with another text file like:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

it works perfectly.

What I do wrong?

Comment: works for me. check your file first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess this file uses the [CR (Carriage Return)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) character (Ascii 13, or `'\r'`) for newlines; on Windows and Linux this would just move the cursor back to column 1, but not move the cursor down to the beginning of a new line.

(Of course such line terminators would not survive copy-paste to Stack Overflow, which is why this cannot be replicated).

You can debug strange characters in a string with `repr`:

```
print(repr(read_map())
```

It will print out the string with all special characters escaped.

---

If you see `\r` in the `repr`ed string, you could try this instead:

```
def read_map():
    with open('map.txt') as f:  # with ensures the file is closed properly
        return f.read().replace('\r', '\n') # replace \r with \n
```

Alternatively supply the `U` flag to [`open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) for universal newlines, which would convert `'\r'`, `'\r\n'` and `'\n'` all to the `\n` upon reading despite the underlying operating system's conventions:

```
def read_map():
    with open('map.txt', 'rU') as f:
        return f.read()
```

---

Comment: If you think that solved your problem then please tick the accept mark next to this answer ;)

Comment: done! sorry im still new to stack overflow. How do i earn reputation?

Comment: @AlexHeld http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/six-simple-tips-to-get-stack-overflow-reputation-fast